# Synchronizing parent height to child height in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm developping with VS 2015 and WPF a mask designer, in which i can drag, move and resize controls.
One of These controls is a Label which has a TextBlock as Content.

This looks in my XAMl like that:

```
<Label Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto">Label</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

For the TextBlock i have set TextWrapping to "Wrap" and Height to "Auto".
When i try to resize the height of the Label at it's allowed minimum, the content of the TextBlock shall still be completely visible.
I tried this with a TextBlock and it worked.
But when i try it with a Label implementing a TextBlock it doesn't work, the content of the TextBlock isn't completely visible anymore.

How can i synchronize the parent's height to the child's height?

Thanks in advance!
Patrick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Ghassen's answer is basically correct. If you want to bind the parent to the child then reverse the answer above.  The reversed code is shown below.

```
<Label x:Name="ParentLabel" Height="{Binding ElementName=ChildBlock, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=ChildBlock, Path=ActualWidth}"  Background="Blue">
      <TextBlock x:Name="ChildBlock" Height="100" Width="100" Background="Green"></TextBlock>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Name of parent and bind its ActualHeight

```
<Label x:Name="parentElementName" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=parentElementName}">Label</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

---

**Edit**

```
   <Label x:Name="parentElementName" Background="AliceBlue" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Child}"HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock  x:Name="Child" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="Auto">Label</TextBlock>
    </Label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what i was looking for. I need to synchrononize the height of the parent with it's child, not the child with it's parent. Is there a way to do this in XAML?